# Create a note in privnote.com using HTTP requests

Tags: bash, curl, httprequest

I'm trying to create a note on [privnote.com](https://privnote.com) from the contents of a file using a simple HTTP request (using cURL). The only information I can find only about this is [this nodeJS app](https://github.com/nonrational/privnote-cli), so I'm using it as a reference, but so far with no luck.

This is what I've got so far:

```
curl -v \
    -H "Host: privnote.com" \
    -H "Connection: keep-alive" \
    -H "Content-Length: 153" \
    -H "Origin: https://privnote.com" \
    -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" \
    -H "User-Agent: privnote-cli/0.1.0 (https://github.com/nonrational/privnote-cli)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -H "Accept: */*" \
    -H "DNT: 1" \
    -H "Referer: https://privnote.com/" \
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" \
    -H "Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6" \
    -X POST \
    --data-binary "@pst-np-v1.pem" \
    "https://privnote.com/legacy/"
```

When I do that request, I get `500 Internal Server Error`. Any ideas on how to get this working?

The end goal is: I'm trying to upload the contents of a file as a note and then fetching the URL all through command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content needs to be sent in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with the following parameters :

- data
- has_manual_pass
- duration_hours
- dont_ask
- data_type
- notify_email
- notify_ref

The `data` parameter contains the message encrypted in AES 256 CBC with a 9 character length password

```sh
password=siK2TDfjC
data=$(cat pst-np-v1.pem | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -k $password -a -md md5)

curl -v 'https://privnote.com/' \
    -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
    --data-urlencode "data=$data" \
    --data "has_manual_pass=false&duration_hours=0&dont_ask=false&data_type=T&notify_email=&notify_ref="
```

The JSON field `note_link` can be extracted using `jq` JSON parser and concatenated to `#$password` to get the full URI

Full example :

```sh
password=siK2TDfjC
message="a not so secret note"
data=$(echo "$message" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -k $password -a -md md5)

note_link=$(curl -s 'https://privnote.com/' \
    -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
    --data-urlencode "data=$data" \
    --data "has_manual_pass=false&duration_hours=0&dont_ask=false&data_type=T&notify_email=&notify_ref=" \
    | jq -r --arg arg $password '.note_link + "#" + $arg')

echo "note URL is $note_link"
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesome, question though, does the password need to be randomly generated? Or can it be the same every time?

Comment: I guess I can do this: `head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c9` to randomly generate a 9 digit password.

Comment: Yes it can be the same, the server doesn't seem to keep a cache of passwords already used, you can also use `pwgen -N 1 9` or `makepasswd --maxchars=9` if you have these tool installed

Comment: Just making a comment here to let people know that this solution is blocked by Privnote and is no longer applicable.